# Can you see the time and/or date a website was visited on the Samsung Browser?

Tags: date-and-time, browser-history, samsung-internet-browser

Can you see the time and/or date a website was visited on the Samsung Browser?

Comment: Have you checked history of the browser to see if it displays date and /or time, i dont have samsung device so i checked chrome and found it atleast shows date so chances are that samsung browser should also have that much info in history

Comment: I did look but didn’t see. Just says “today”, then “last 7 days”, but if the browser is already on a page when you open it, it’s gonna show up under history for that day. I was really hoping for more specific details. Thank you!!

Answer (score -1):

You definitely can view the history with details about date and time. In the latest version of Samsung Browser, go to Bookmarks tab and then you will see the history section there.
I'm pretty sure in all browsers you can do such a thing.

Comment: Thank you. I have looked and all I see is where it says “Today” then underneath that it says “Last 7 days”... so I’m not sure how to tell when the website was actually visited. If I open the browser and it’s on that page, it’s going to show up under “today”, but I don’t see a way to see the time or anything. Any ideas on where else I might be able to see that info? If I click the website it just takes me there.

Comment: My bad, you are right. I doesn't show the exact date or time. Try using other browsers, I think they provide more info. For example, in FireFox the history is classified based on month.

Comment: Thanks! Just needing the info for someone who’s already using Samsung Internet. Darn, was really hoping there was a way!!